# Ubuntu 20.04 taking way too much ram

Tags: ram, memory-usage, memory-leak, ram-usage

Some time ago I noticed a lot of ram(1.8/8GB) being used when my system was idle with only a day of uptime. I had to reinstall my Ubuntu because of some reason and now the ram usage has risen up much more. I only have a 26 hours of uptime and this is the result of `free -m`  when my system is idle

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      7738        3622        2810         136        1304        3720
Swap:     2047         271        1776
```

This is 3.6GB/8GB when my system is idle. The ram usage remains same when I turn off all the extensions too.This is way too much. I'm also posting a screenshot of processes running at this time. And this is not that my system automatically adjusts ram when I open applications, I'm only able to open very limited applications from before. This is way more than windows has ever used on idle.

[image]

Can someone please help me avoid this issue?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are illustrating with the screenshot? was that at a different time as the free command?.... the screenshot barely shows half a gig being used...

Comment: your gnome-shell is using only 173MB of ram.. I don't see any problems

Comment: @WU-TANG That had a time difference of max 30 sec. I don't know which processes are taking my ram but they somehow are

Comment: @Lews I don't have a problem with gnome-shell but ubuntu in whole

Comment: Are you assigning/sharing memory to graphics??? that usually comes off the top though... But how much memory do you have consumed when you boot and log in?

Comment: to know which process in consuming more memory you just need to type **top -n1 -o %MEM**. Try to past here the output.

Comment: @WU-TANG I don't know what you been by assigning sharing memory to graphics. I don't have a external graphic card and haven't done anything to change configurations of the same. I have about 1.1GB-1.2GB when I boot in.

Comment: @Lews I'll paste the output here when my system starts eating ram again. I just restarted so that can can a while. And I tried the command but it doesn't anything different from system monitor feed.